# Regex for tabular content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to get the specific values from the .txt file using NodeJS. Hope using Regex is the best way to achieve this. So i tried below code from my side, here i can able to get the values from non-tabular area .

```
var res4 = data.match(/\d*.\d*%id/g);
var res5 = data.match(/\d*\d*k free/g);
console.log(res4); **// [ '93.2%id' ]**
console.log(res5); **//[ '862100k free', '6143996k free' ]**
```

But when i am trying to get the value inside tabular format of the .txt file , i am unable to do it. Below is the source .txt file for your reference. Here i need cuic_reporting(in command column) and its corresponding %CPU column value for it .Kindly help me in it. Thanks.

```
 top - 02:51:10 up 176 days, 23:47,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.09, 0.07
Tasks: 208 total,   1 running, 207 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.7%us,  1.9%sy,  0.1%ni, 93.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16336156k total, 15474056k used,   862100k free,   362908k buffers
Swap:  6143996k total,        0k used,  6143996k free,  8415656k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20967 OSAdmin   30  10 1299m 120m  26m S 35.7  0.8   0:03.47 java
14231 tomcat    20   0 3422m 3.1g  22m S  2.0 20.0  10869:37 cuic_reporting
    1 root      20   0 19572 1812 1244 S  0.0  0.0   2:59.65 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  25:22.51 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:42.43 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 stopper/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:14.34 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  25:47.89 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 stopper/1
```

Thanks !!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your first pattern can be written as `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?%id\b` using a single `\d+` matching 1+ digits where you have to escape the dot to match it literally.

If the value can also be without a decimal part, you can make that optional

The second pattern could be written as `\b\d+k free\b` using a single `\d+` to match 1+ digits as well. You could use word boundaries to prevent the word being part of a larger word and get partial matches.

---

To get the value of *cuic_reporting* you could use a capturing group and use a repeating group to match the values between the %CPU and cuic_reporting.

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){2}[^\S\r\n]+cuic_reporting\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTQ9Nc/1)

```js
let str = ` top - 02:51:10 up 176 days, 23:47,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.09, 0.07
Tasks: 208 total,   1 running, 207 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.7%us,  1.9%sy,  0.1%ni, 93.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16336156k total, 15474056k used,   862100k free,   362908k buffers
Swap:  6143996k total,        0k used,  6143996k free,  8415656k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20967 OSAdmin   30  10 1299m 120m  26m S 35.7  0.8   0:03.47 java
14231 tomcat    20   0 3422m 3.1g  22m S  2.0 20.0  10869:37 cuic_reporting
    1 root      20   0 19572 1812 1244 S  0.0  0.0   2:59.65 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  25:22.51 migration/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   2:42.43 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 stopper/0
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:14.34 watchdog/0
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  25:47.89 migration/1
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 stopper/1`;

let pattern = /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+){2}[^\S\r\n]+cuic_reporting\b/;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);
```

Comment: @ The Fourth bird, Sorry for the late response , due to personal issues i  just opened my account.. You saved my life , Its working perfect..Thanks..

Comment: I need your input for one of small condition in above logic.You currently taken cuic_reporting and its corresponding cpu value.  But in one of my case i need cuic_reporting cpu percentage but it should also match with second column user as well.    Say example here i need CPU value of CUIC reporting as well as it should match with Tomcat(user in second column in above table).If both condition cuic-reporting and Tomcat matches then i need the CPU value of it. Can you help here ?.

Comment: @Mohan Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/1C6XiZ/1

Comment: @FourthBird . You are Great!..Its returning the cpu value after decimal point.(if we have cpu value 2.0 only 0 is returning). Is it possible to take whole decimal number value - 2.0, can u help me ?.

Comment: @Mohan Ah I see, like this then :-) https://regex101.com/r/KxMvsj/1

Comment: working Perfect..Really you helped me a lot...Thank you!..

Answer (score 0):

I give you my opinion about how i would do:

After read the file with fs module for example, i would try to split the data of the txt (either by tabulator('\t') and also line break ('\n' or '\r') if you don't read line by line) and then you can successful apply regex to each element of the resulting array.

I hope it help you!

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match

Answer (score 0):

You could first refine the `top` command with parameters so it becomes easier to extract the data you want:

```
ps -p `pgrep -d "," cuic_reporting` -o %cpu
```

This will directly output the CPU usage and make parsing the result way easier.